# AltBeacon not scanning beacons in background using foreground service. RegionBootstrap/ BootstrapNotifier implementation is also not working

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I have a service which looks for beacons when the user enters any building based on the location it will return back valid beacon regions. The `BeaconRanger` service is then triggered and should start scanning for the beacons in that region. This should work for both background and foreground state of the application. It also updates time intervals based on the app foreground state and background state.

*Update scan periods in background*: **can find code in updateScanPeriods()**

```
    private static Long BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 10 * 1000l; // 10 sec
    private static Long FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 1100l; // 1.1 sec
    private static Long BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 10 * 60 * 1000l; // 10 min
    private static Long FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 5 * 1000l; // 5 sec
```

*Update scan periods in foreground*: **can find code in updateScanPeriods()**

```
    private static Long BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 1100l; // 1.1 sec
    private static Long FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 1100l; // 1.1 sec
    private static Long BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 4 * 1000l; // 5 sec
    private static Long FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 3 * 1000l; // 3 sec
```

*Set background mode*: **can find code in public void onEventMainThread(BeaconRangerBackgroundSetting beaconRangerBackgroundSetting)**

```
            if (beaconRangerBackgroundSetting.status) {
                if (beaconManager != null && beaconManager.isBound(this))
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
            } else {
                if (beaconManager != null && beaconManager.isBound(this))
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
            }
```

I am able to get the valid regions in background state and pass it to `BeaconRanger` class but the ranged beacons list is always empty from the Altbeacon manager unless I open the app again. I implemented the RegionBootstrap/ BootstrapNotifier for background startup but the result is the same.

I wanted to know if something is wrong with my implementation?

```
public class BeaconRanger extends Service implements BeaconConsumer, BootstrapNotifier {

    private static final String TAG = "ArubaBeacons";
    private static final int MAX_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000; // 1 min
    private static final int MIN_INTERVAL = 25 * 1000; // 25 sec
    private static final int MAX_RETRY_TIME = 2 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;
    private static Long BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 10 * 1000l; // 10 sec
    private static Long FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 1100l; // 1.1 sec
    private static Long BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 10 * 60 * 1000l; // 10 min
    private static Long FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM = 5 * 1000l; // 5 sec
    private static Long BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 1100l; // 1.1 sec
    private static Long FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 1100l; // 1.1 sec
    private static Long BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 4 * 1000l; // 5 sec
    private static Long FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW = 3 * 1000l; // 3 sec
    private ArrayList<Model.beacon> beaconList = new ArrayList<Model.beacon>();
    private ArrayList<Region> regions = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Region> lastRangedRegions = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Region> rangedRegions = new ArrayList<>();
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private  BeaconApplication mApp;
    private long mLastRangeTime = 0;
    private long mLastPostedTime = 0;
    private long mLastRetryTime = 0;
    private int retryCount = 0;
    private EventBus mBus = EventBus.getDefault();
    private ArrayList<String> regionIds = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Model.beacon> mLastRangedBeacons = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Model.beacon> mLastUpdatedBeacons = new ArrayList<>();
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private int mLastBeaconSetting = -1;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            mApp =  BeaconApplication.mInstance;
            mApp.mBeaconRanger = this;
            mBus.registerSticky(this);
            new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);


            beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

            // set the duration of the scan
            updateScanPeriods();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                setForeground();
            }
            beaconManager.bind(this);


            BeaconManager.setDebug(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e("Exception in onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setForeground() {
        try {
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "location_service_notifications";
            String channelName = "Location Service Notifications";
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);


            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_location);
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.arcangel_location_beacon_notification_title));
            builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.arcangel_location_beacon_notification_text));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName())
                    .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, notificationChannel.getId());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            int v = beaconManager.getForegroundServiceNotificationId();
            startForeground(2, builder.build());
            if (beaconManager.getForegroundServiceNotificationId() < 0) {
                beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 2);
                beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
                updateScanPeriods();
            }

            Timber.d("started Foreground");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e("Exception in setForeground: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void updateScanPeriods() {
        int mCurrentBeaconSetting;
        Long backgroundScanPeriod;
        Long foregroundScanPeriod;
        Long backgroundBetweenScanPeriod;
        Long foregroundBetweenScanPeriod;


        if ((mApp.isAppVisible()) { // app in the foreground
            mCurrentBeaconSetting = 0;
            backgroundScanPeriod = BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW;
            foregroundScanPeriod = FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW;
            backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW;
            foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_LOW;

        } else { // app in the background
            mCurrentBeaconSetting = 1;
            backgroundScanPeriod = BACKGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM;
            foregroundScanPeriod = FOREGROUND_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM;
            backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = BACKGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM;
            foregroundBetweenScanPeriod = FOREGROUND_BETWEEN_SCAN_PERIOD_MEDIUM;
        }

        if (mLastBeaconSetting != mCurrentBeaconSetting && beaconManager != null) {
            beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(backgroundScanPeriod);
            beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(foregroundScanPeriod);
            beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(backgroundBetweenScanPeriod); // callback time between scans background
            beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(foregroundBetweenScanPeriod); // callback time between scans foreground
            mLastBeaconSetting = mCurrentBeaconSetting;
            try {
                beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void checkRangedRegionsValidity() {
        if (regionIds.size() <= 0) {
            beaconList.clear();
            for (Region duplicateRegion : beaconManager.getRangedRegions()) {
                try {
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(duplicateRegion);
                    beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(duplicateRegion);
                    regionBootstrap.removeRegion(duplicateRegion);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mLastRangedBeacons.clear();
        }
    }


   // called by a different service, will give a valid region based on certain parameters like inside an building or location. If no condition is satisfies gives an empty array
    public void setBeaconRegionIds(ArrayList<String> regionIds) {
        this.regionIds = regionIds;
        checkRangedRegionsValidity();
        updateScanPeriods();

        try {
            regions.clear();
            for (String regionId : regionIds) {
                regions.add(new Region(regionId.toLowerCase(), Identifier.parse(regionId.toLowerCase()), null, null));
            }
            if (lastRangedRegions.size() == 0 || !lastRangedRegions.equals(regions)) {
                lastRangedRegions = new ArrayList<>(regions);

                if (beaconManager != null && beaconManager.isBound(this))
                    onBeaconServiceConnect();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(TAG + e);
        }
    }


    private void startRanging() {

        try {
            if (canRun()) {
                rangedRegions = (ArrayList<Region>) beaconManager.getRangedRegions();
                if (rangedRegions.removeAll(regions)) {
                    for (Region duplicateRegion : rangedRegions) {
                        beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(duplicateRegion);
                        beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(duplicateRegion);
                    }
                }

                rangedRegions = (ArrayList<Region>) beaconManager.getRangedRegions();
                if (regions.size() > 0 && !rangedRegions.equals(regions)) {
                    regions.removeAll(rangedRegions);
                    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, regions);

                    for (Region newRegion : regions) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
//                            regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, newRegion);
                        }

                        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(newRegion);
                        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(newRegion);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void addRangerNotifier() {
        if (beaconManager == null)
            return;
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {


                for (Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < beaconList.size(); i++) {
                        String arubaDuplicate = beaconList.get(i).id.trim();
                        String aruba = (oneBeacon.getId1().toString().trim() + ":" + oneBeacon.getId2().toInt() + ":" + oneBeacon.getId3().toInt()).trim();
                        if (aruba.equals(arubaDuplicate)) {
                            beaconList.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                    Timber.d(TAG + "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " id:" + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
                    beaconList.add(new Model.beacon(oneBeacon.getId1().toString().trim(), oneBeacon.getId2().toInt(), oneBeacon.getId3().toInt(), oneBeacon.getDistance()));
                    retryCount = 0;
                }
                boolean post = beaconsDifferInOrderByNth(mLastRangedBeacons, beaconList, 4);
                mLastRangedBeacons = new ArrayList<>(beaconList);
                if (mLastPostedTime < (System.currentTimeMillis() - 4500) && mApp.mState != null && mApp.mState.getLastKnownBeacons() == 0 && beaconList.size() > 0 && regionIds.size() > 0) {
                    mLastPostedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    mBus.post(new BeaconRanger.MessageBeaconsRanged());
                }
                checkRangedRegionsValidity();

            }
        });

    }


    public void onEventMainThread(BeaconRangerBackgroundSetting beaconRangerBackgroundSetting) {
        try {

            if (beaconRangerBackgroundSetting.status) {
                if (beaconManager != null && beaconManager.isBound(this))
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
            } else {
                if (beaconManager != null && beaconManager.isBound(this))
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
            }
            updateScanPeriods();
            mBus.removeStickyEvent(beaconRangerBackgroundSetting);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        if (beaconManager != null && (beaconManager.getRangingNotifiers().size() <= 0))
            addRangerNotifier();
        startRanging();

    }


    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Timber.d("didEnterRegion: " + region);
        try {
            rangedRegions = (ArrayList<Region>) beaconManager.getRangedRegions();
            if (!rangedRegions.contains(region) || rangedRegions.indexOf(region) < 0)
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Timber.d("didExitRegion: " + region);
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
        Timber.d("didDetermineStateForRegion: " + region);

        if (i == 1) {
            try {
                rangedRegions = (ArrayList<Region>) beaconManager.getRangedRegions();
                if ((rangedRegions.contains(region) || rangedRegions.indexOf(region) >= 0) && mLastRangedBeacons.size() == 0) {
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } else if (!rangedRegions.contains(region) || rangedRegions.indexOf(region) < 0) {
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Are you are getting the didRangeBeaconsInRegion callbacks in the background (even if they have a beacons count of 0)?  What phone model and OS version are you testing with?  Can you show your LogCat output and describe specifically what is unexpected in that output?

Comment: Yes I am getting callbacks in the background, just the beacons count is empty. I am using Samsung Galaxy S8+ (Android 8.0.0). I did not enable the debug mode on the Altbeacon manager, can do that if required and collect logs from logcat.

Comment: It sounds like the OS is blocking BLE scan results in the background.  Two possibilities I can think of on Samsung: (1) If your beacon is advertising a non-standard manufacturer id in its BLE header, it might not match the background scan filter.  You can check this by testing with a software beacon transmitter on a second device (Use BeaconScope for Android or Locate for iOS).  (2) If your build.gradle targetsdk is set to an old version and you have not obtained the runtime location permission from Android, background scans will be blocked.

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest Android Beacon Library version -- there was a fix awhile back to allow background scanning on Samsung Android 8.1+ (although this should not affect you if you really are using Android 8.0 and not 8.1+)

Comment: I am using the latest version of the library `org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.1`. So you think nothing is wrong with the above implementation and its some possibilities that you have mentioned? @davidgyoung

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question, so it is possible I have missed something in my quick review that causes a problem.  Lots of customizations sometimes cause surprising side effects.  You might try the library reference app and see if it detects in the background.  If so, that indicates something in your custom code is causing the issue.

Comment: @davidgyoung one more thing is this is all inside an sdk not in an application. Also I added the BootstrapNotifier for a `Service` inside the sdk instead of an `Application` class inside the app. Will this make any difference?

Comment: Adding an Android Service opens a new world of complexities.  RegionBootstrap is not designed to be used within a Service, so any examples of its use or descriptions of how it works that you see are invalidated by using it in a Service.  I would recommend not using it and instead calling  `beaconManager.bind(...)` and then start monitoring with `beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(...)`.  Be sure you understand the lifecycle of your Service and know that it is your responsibility to make it start back up automatically if it is killed by the OS for whatever reason.